# Fitting a Gamma Distribution to Streamflows with R

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

Hello I have a monthly average of stream flow for the last 100 years:

```
Sep <-
c(50504.61, 31903.57, 20575.81, 51250, 20282.16, 19932.05, 22302.73, 
24777.73, 27681.94, 18676.9, 28587.23, 29030.58, 24433.3, 18785.24, 
21913.74, 33662.53, 23215.58, 35792.85, 13766.63, 41484.56, 16209.67, 
74759.93, 19730.94, 61532.38, 24404.35, 14988.49, 24505.1, 19911.57, 
10058.62, 20984.86, 24913.8, 21067.56, 37107.83, 23730.15, 18556.58, 
24130.02, 14550.06, 21667.81, 11748.43, 17464.65, 15869.2, 27497.25, 
13161.09, 14842.04, 15144.44, 18796.16, 24514.99, 14315.39, 17463.56, 
12698.22, 10528.03, 35689.17, 15496.81, 11170.44, 11593.22, 30230.25, 
14554.43, 25971.54, 12939.35, 30981.11, 12630.06, 18271.7, 14998.52, 
21462.35, 39960.48, 23928.06, 20261.68, 23808.23, 12809.67, 18762.68, 
17108.04, 12861.55, 14521.27, 14215.91, 21513.8, 18797.29, 37495.3, 
27068.98, 37775.56, 26099.67, 34931.63, 23563.04, 19916.69, 15545.58, 
19366.38, 27494.53, 22375.44, 27635.01, 18280.28, 26641.43, 18894.12, 
42866.85, 25925.63, 38156.57, 18015.56)
```

I am trying to fit a Gamma Distribution to the data with the function:

```
fit.gamma <- fitdist(Sep, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
```

and it gives an error:

> simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs
>   =   data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,        lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite
>   finite-difference value [2]>   Error in fitdist(Sep, distr = "gamma",
>   method = "mle") :     the function mle failed to estimate the
>   parameters,
>                   with the error code 100

I am using the packages

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(sm)
library(Rlab)
library(MASS)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What's your question? Please share your data using `dput()`. See more here: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you sayng you ran the code you're showing and didn't get the result you expected or wanted?  If so, what was the result you expected or wanted?

Comment: What makes you think a gamma fits your data?

Comment: The question had a data example in a poor format, changed to dput(Sep). And there was no real question, I have included the error message.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posing to this web site.  I am trying to find a best fit gamma distribution for my data set. I am new coding in R and I don't understand the error message. Could someone explain this error message to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gamma distribution` has two parameters and both are positive. `fitdist` function uses `optim` function to find those parameters. However, without any user specified limit, `optim` will try even (infeasible) negative parameters during iteration resulting in `NaNs`. Setting the limit `lower = c(0, 0)`, will fix this error.

Credit to this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158171)

```r
library(fitdistrplus)

fit.gamma <- fitdist(Sep, distr = "gamma", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0))

# Check result
plot(fit.gamma)
```

[image]

```r
# Goodness-of-fit statistics
gofstat(fit.gamma)

#> Goodness-of-fit statistics
#>                              1-mle-gamma
#> Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic  0.09099753
#> Cramer-von Mises statistic    0.16861125
#> Anderson-Darling statistic    1.07423429
#> 
#> Goodness-of-fit criteria
#>                                1-mle-gamma
#> Akaike's Information Criterion    2004.836
#> Bayesian Information Criterion    2009.944
```

Created on 2018-03-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).